# ordering a self-referencing table by DFS search in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a self refrenced table that represents some data like below:

```
    declare @table table( 
    ID int,
    ParentID int,
    Name varchar(50),
    levelNode int
)
declare @Temptable table( 
    ID int,
    ParentID int,
    Name varchar(50),
    levelNode int
)
declare @maxlevel int

insert into @table (ID,ParentID,Name,levelNode) select 11,null,'A',1
insert into @table (ID,ParentID,Name,levelNode) select 12,11,'B-1',2
insert into @table (ID,ParentID,Name,levelNode) select 13,11,'B-2',2
insert into @table (ID,ParentID,Name,levelNode) select 14,12,'B-1-1',3
insert into @table (ID,ParentID,Name,levelNode) select 15,12,'B-1-2',3
insert into @table (ID,ParentID,Name,levelNode) select 16,12,'B-1-3',3
insert into @table (ID,ParentID,Name,levelNode) select 17,13,'B-2-1',3
insert into @table (ID,ParentID,Name,levelNode) select 18,13,'B-2-2',3
insert into @table (ID,ParentID,Name,levelNode) select 19,13,'B-2-3',3
insert into @table (ID,ParentID,Name,levelNode) select 20,19,'B-2-3-1',4
insert into @table (ID,ParentID,Name,levelNode) select 21,19,'B-2-3-2',4
insert into @table (ID,ParentID,Name,levelNode) select 22,17,'B-2-1-1',4
insert into @table (ID,ParentID,Name,levelNode) select 23,17,'B-2-1-2',4

declare @ID int
select @ID=11;
With ret AS(
    select * from @table
    where ID=@ID
    union all
    select t.* from @table t inner join ret r ON t.ParentID=r.ID 
)

insert into @Temptable select * from ret where ID<>@ID
order by ??????????????????

select * from @Temptable
```

[image]

I want to order them like this:

[image]

What should I write in order by section!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8838/1)

```
INSERT INTO @Temptable 
SELECT * 
FROM   ret 
WHERE  id <> @ID 
ORDER  BY Substring(NAME, 3, 1), 
          Substring(NAME, 5, 1), 
          Substring(NAME, 7, 1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help but the names are symbolic, they just show the relations in this specific sample... in reality they are the name of the items... I selected this names to make my question more clear... I should find an answer that is based on `Id` and `ParentId` (and `level` if it's needed).

Comment: @mj-y By your expected result i dono how to order by using Id and parentId. there is no order in your output

Comment: It is a self referencing table, the parent id is the id of a row in the current table. If you follow the ids and parents you can create the tree of the table data. I want to have a `(DFS: Depth first search)` ordering of this table data.